# Axios request app on android doesn't work, react native

Tags: android, reactjs, request, axios, native

I am having a problem that I do not know why this is  happing, I am using axios to make request a api, it working fine on emulator, but when I build the apk and install it on the phone, looks like it is not getting the request, I installed the same apk on emulador bluestacks and is working fine, it is my first app react native, and I do not know why this happen, some one had a experience like it ? and could help

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it, to work in Release Apk, I need to put

android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"

in the tag application on android manifest